# Splitting a string into an array of n words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to turn this:

```
"This is a test this is a test"
```

into this:

```
["This is a", "test this is", "a test"]
```

I tried this:

```
const re = /\b[\w']+(?:[^\w\n]+[\w']+){0,2}\b/
const wordList = sample.split(re)
console.log(wordList)
```

But I got this:

```
[ '',
  ' ',
  ' ']
```

Why is this?

(The rule is to split the string every N words.)

Comment: What is the rule to follow to split the string?

Comment: @A.J I updated the question.

Comment: `.split()` doesn't include the delimiter so it does the opposite of what you want. You need to do a regular regex search (with a `g` modifier) instead of split.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method will split the string by the matched content so it won't include the matched string within the result array.

Use the [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with a global flag (`g`) on your regular expression instead:

```js
var sample="This is a test this is a test"

const re = /\b[\w']+(?:\s+[\w']+){0,2}/g;
const wordList = sample.match(re);
console.log(wordList);
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/ax4KGe/1)

Answer (score 8):

As an alternate approach, you can split string by space and the merge chunks in batch.

```js
function splitByWordCount(str, count) {
  var arr = str.split(' ')
  var r = [];
  while (arr.length) {
    r.push(arr.splice(0, count).join(' '))
  }
  return r;
}

var a = "This is a test this is a test";
console.log(splitByWordCount(a, 3))
console.log(splitByWordCount(a, 2))
```

Comment: Awesome! +1 for splitting text in chunks.

Comment: Can you explain to me what `arr.length` means in the while loop argument?

Comment: @MekelIlyasa every array has a property called `length` which denotes the number of items it holds. `while(arr.length)` will check if length is greater than 0, as in JS 0 is considered as falsey. Also, in the next line, I'm removing items using `.splice`, so it will update `.length`. Hope its clear now

Answer (score 4):

your code is good to go. but not with split. split will treat it as a delimitor. 
for instance something like this:

```
var arr = "1, 1, 1, 1";
arr.split(',') === [1, 1, 1, 1] ;
//but 
arr.split(1) === [', ', ', ', ', ', ', '];
```

Instead use `match` or `exec`. like this

```js
var x = "This is a test this is a test";
var re = /\b[\w']+(?:[^\w\n]+[\w']+){0,2}\b/g
var y = x.match(re);
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use whitespace special character (`\s`) and `match` function instead of `split`:

```
var wordList = sample.text().match(/\s?(?:\w+\s?){1,3}/g);
```

Split breaks string where regex matches. Match returns whatever that is matched.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8eohmrwn/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You could split like that:

```js
var str = 'This is a test this is a test';
var wrd = str.split(/((?:\w+\s+){1,3})/);
console.log(wrd);
```

But, you have to delete empty elements from the array.